# pdf comments and insert / delete / extract pages in Evince

Tags: software-recommendation, evince

I use Evince / Ubuntu 12.04 at home.
I use(d) all Windows up to 7 except Vista at work.
PDFs are more widespread each year.
Evince is a great reader.
Business use needs Office and Acrobat Standard capabilities.
Open Office / Libre Office work great.
I use pdf mod to delte / add / combine pdfs.
True comments in pdfs seems to be missing.
It would be better to have a native app vs a wine app.
Are there plans to add commenting and insert / extract / delete page capabilities to Evince?
Seems like that a serious missing part of Ubuntu / Linux.

Comment: [This wiki page](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/PDF) has an extensive list of programs to edit pdf. Downside is, it is in german, you might need via google or somesuch.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about Evince plans, but used this link to get "pdf-edit" software filtered to Linux platform.

http://alternativeto.net/tag/pdf-editor/?platform=linux

What seems to be a nice app is PdfMod. It is not that you can edit it directly in Evince, but it is probably next best thing regarding "user-friendly-PDF-editing" approach. :-)